# SQL Server 2008 R2 Licensing

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I want to add a named instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 on one of the server. Server already has 2 named instances on it. My question is, do I need to buy a SQL Server 2008 R2 license for this new instance or not? The server has SQL Server 2008 R2 (standard edition) installed on it.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on how you licensed SQL server unfortunately. Even if you did supply all the relevant details the Question would be Too Localized. You're best option is to call a MS Partner or Reseller.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless what anyone here tells you, you need to contact a licensing specialist on this. The terms on licenses are so complex these days that unless you deal with licensing all the time you're bound to make a mistake.